# Python any() - does every number return true except 0?

Tags: python

I have multiple quantity input fields, which only allows positive integer values, on a web page.

My first code looks like this:

```
quantities = []
for form in forms:
    qty= form.cleaned_data['qty']
    if qty:
        quantities.append(qty)
if not quantities:
    raise forms.ValidationError("You didn't choose any books")
```

After reviewing my code, I found a shorter version:

```
if not any([form.cleaned_data['qty'] for form in forms]):
    raise forms.ValidationError("You didn't choose any books")
```

Will this always work? Does every integer evaluate to `True` except `0`?

Comment: What happened when you tested it?  What did you find when you researched the truth values of numbers?

Comment: It worked after testing it, I've searched for this type of question but I couldn't find a specific answer to my question because this also relates to the any() function of python.

Comment: Specifically see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/5858851) (the upvoted one, rather than the accepted one).

Comment: Keep in mind that "nonzero" and "positive" are completely different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, yes.

Unless specially defined, most objects in python are considered True.

See source & exceptions below:

> [4. Built-in Types (Python 3 documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)
>
> 4.1. Truth Value Testing
>
> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below.
>
> ***By default, an object is considered true*** unless its class defines either a **bool**() method that returns False or a **len**() method that returns zero, when called with the object. Here are most of the built-in objects considered false:
>
> Constants defined to be false:
>
> **None** and **False.**
>
> zero of any numeric type: **0**, **0.0**, **0j**, **Decimal(0)**, **Fraction(0, 1)**
>
> empty sequences and collections: **''**, **()**, **[]**, **{}**, **set()**, **range(0)**
>
> Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return **0** or **False** for false and **1** or **True** for true, unless otherwise stated.
>
> (Important exception: the Boolean operations or and and always return one of their operands.)

Answer (score 0):

Given integers (`int`s) as your domain, the answer is yes. The only *falsy* integer value in Python is `0`. All other integers are `True` when evaluated as a `bool`.

Comment: Although everything you said true, Alex answer is better: a) it directs to documentation, b) it answers "Why the only falsy integer value in Python is 0".
And you just state it as Holy Truth